# How does XorShift32 works?

Tags: c, static

I have this homework where i need to implement xorshift32(i can t use anything else) so i can generate some numbers but i don t understand how the algorithm works or how to implement it.

I am trying to print the generated number but i don t know how to call the xorshift32 function because of the state[static 1] argument.

```
uint32_t xorshift32(uint32_t state[static 1])
{
    uint32_t x = state[0];
    x ^= x << 13;
    x ^= x >> 17;
    x ^= x << 5;
    state[0] = x;
    return x;
}
```

I do not have much information on xorshft32 other that what is on wikipedia(en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).

Comment: Can you even *compile* that function?  It does not conform to standard C (with respect to the function parameter), so if your compiler accepts it then some language extension is in play.  You'll need to check your implementation's documentation (or maybe your class notes) to find out what it means.  On the other hand, maybe there's simply a typo there.  It would make more sense if the `static` keyword were removed, or perhaps moved to the beginning of the function declaration.

Comment: You need to tell us what the `xorshift32` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky here is the wikipeda: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift . I don t even know to explain it to you. It s a number generator using xor and shift made  by a guy. The teacher didn t tell us much either

Comment: @PredescuEduard that information belongs _into_ the question. You can [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C code in the wikipedia article is somewhat misleading:

Here is a working example that uses both the 32 bit and the 64 bit versions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* The state word must be initialized to non-zero */
uint32_t xorshift32(uint32_t state[])
{
  /* Algorithm "xor" from p. 4 of Marsaglia, "Xorshift RNGs" */
  uint32_t x = state[0];
  x ^= x << 13;
  x ^= x >> 17;
  x ^= x << 5;
  state[0] = x;
  return x;
}

uint64_t xorshift64(uint64_t state[])
{
  uint64_t x = state[0];
  x ^= x << 13;
  x ^= x >> 7;
  x ^= x << 17;
  state[0] = x;
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t state[1] = {1234};  // "seed" (can be anthing but 0)

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    printf("%u\n", xorshift32(state));
  }

  uint64_t state64[1] = { 1234 };  // "seed" (can be anthing but 0)

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    printf("%llu\n", xorshift64(state64));
  }
}
```

The mathematical aspects are explained in the wikipedia article and in it's footnotes.

The rest is basic C language knowledge,  `^` is the C bitwise XOR operator.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment to the good [answer by Jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886716/1475978).

The Xorshift variants, `rand()`, and basically all random number generator functions, are actually [pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). They are not "real random", because the sequence of numbers they generate depends on their internal state; but they are ["pseudorandom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness), because if you do not know the generator internal state, the sequence of numbers they generate is random in the statistical sense.

[George Marsaglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Marsaglia), the author of the Xorshift family of pseudorandom number generators, also developed a set of statistical tools called [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) that can be used to analyse the "randomness" of the sequences generated.  Currently, the [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) tests are probably the most widely used and trusted; in particular, the 160-test BigCrush set.

The sequence generated by ordinary pseudorandom number generators often allows one to determine the internal state of the generator.  This means that observing a long enough generated sequence, allows one to fairly reliably predict the future sequence. [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) avoid that, usually by applying a cryptographically secure hash function to the output; one would need a catalog of the entire sequence to be able to follow it. When the periods are longer than 2<sup>256</sup> or so, there is not enough baryonic matter in the entire observable universe to store the sequence.

My own favourite PRNG is Xorshift64*, which has a period of 2<sup>64</sup>-1, and passes all but the MatrixRank test in BigCrush. In C99 and later, you can implement it using

```
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
    uint64_t  state;
} prng_state;

static inline uint64_t prng_u64(prng_state *const p)
{
    uint64_t  state = p->state;
    state ^= state >> 12;
    state ^= state << 25;
    state ^= state >> 27;
    p->state = state;
    return state * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
}
```

The state can be initialized to any nonzero `uint64_t`. (A zero state will lead the generator to generate all zeros till infinity. The period is 2<sup>64</sup>-1, because the generator will have each 64-bit state (excluding zero) exactly once during each period.)

It is good enough for most use cases, and extremely fast.  It belongs to the class of [linear-feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) pseudorandom number generators.

Note that the variant which returns an uniform distribution between 0 and 1,

```
static inline double prng_one(prng_state *p)
{
    return prng_u64(p) / 18446744073709551616.0;
}
```

uses the high bits; the high 32 bits of the sequence does pass all BigCrunch tests in TestU01 suite, so this is a surprisingly good (randomness and efficiency) generator for double-precision uniform random numbers -- my typical use case.

The format above allows multiple independent generators in a single process, by specifying the generator state as a parameter. If the basic generator is implemented in a header file (thus the `static inline`; it is a preprocessor macro-like function), you can switch between generators by switching between header files, and recompiling the binary.

(You are usually better off by using a single generator, unless you use multiple threads in a pseudorandom number heavy simulator, in which case using a separate generator for each thread will help a lot; avoids cacheline ping-pong between threads competing for the generator state, in particular.)

The `rand()` function in most C standard library implementations is a [linear-congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).  They often suffer from poor choices of the coefficients, and nowadays, also from the relative slowness of the modulo operator (when the modulus is not a power of two).

The most widely used pseudorandom number generator is the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), by Makoto Matsumoto (松本 眞) and Takuji Nishimura (西村 拓士). It is a twisted generalized linear feedback shift register, and has quite a large state (about 2500 bytes) and very long period (2<sup>19937</sup>-1).

---

When we talk of *true* random number generators, we usually mean a combination of a pseudorandom number generator (usually a cryptographically secure one), and a source of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)); random bits with at least some degree of true physical randomness.

In Linux, Mac OS, and BSDs at least, the operating system kernel exposes a source of pseudorandom numbers ([`getentropy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) in Linux and OpenBSD, [`getrandom()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) in Linux, `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/arandom`, `/dev/random` in many Unixes, and so on).  Entropy is gathered from physical electronic sources, like internal processor latencies, physical interrupt line timings, (spinning disk) hard drive timings, possibly even keyboard and mice.  Many motherboards and some processors even have [hardware random number sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) that can be used as sources for entropy (or even directly as "trusted randomness sources").

The [exclusive-or operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive-or) (`^` in C) is used to mix in randomness to the generator state.  This works, because exclusive-or between a known bit and a random bit results in a random bit; XOR preserves randomness. When mixing entropy pools (with some degree of randomness in the bit states) using XOR, the result will have at least as much entropy as the sources had.

Note that that does *not* mean that you get "better" random numbers by mixing the output of two or more generators.  The statistics of true randomness is hard for humans to grok (just look at how poor the common early `rand()` implementations were! HORRIBLE!).  It is better to pick a generator (or a set of generators to switch between at compile time, or at run time) that passes the BigCrunch tests, and ensure it has a good random initial state on every run.  That way you leverage the work of many mathematicians and others who have worked on these things for decades, and can concentrate on the other stuff, what you yourself are good at.