# Does rand() function in C have a limit?

Tags: c

Here is a sample code

`int x = rand() % 90000;`

When I was doing something like this I realized all the numbers were around 0 - 30000.
Is there a limit for this? If there is how can I use it without limits?

Comment: See [the specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html).

Comment: Please see this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX

Comment: Also [please don't use `rand()`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) (and there are plenty of other resources saying the same).

Comment: @Dirk Then can you suggest a portable alternative that works in C? This is not C++.

Comment: @Andrew I use C++ (much) more often but AFAICR it is mostly a library issue which makes it a portability issue: while _your machine_ may be fine, somebody else's may not be.  I think the recommendation is to use `random()` instead.  And then there are of course external libraries such as the Mersenne Twister etc pp -- lots of material out there on this.

Comment: @AndrewSun: Use `rand()`, just don't use modulo. E.g. use something like `while( (x = rand() & 0x3FFF) >= 9000 ) {}` to limit the range without causing an uneven distribution (where the last number, 8999 in your case, is less likely than other numbers).

Comment: @Brendan Not sure I agree, `rand()` is pretty universally discouraged and has been for a long time. So unless the task is trivial, I'd look for a better replacement.  There are lots.

Comment: @Brendan: OP does not want to limit the range; they want to extend it. Their modulus is 90000, not 9000.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah - I missed that. That's trivial to fix (just combine 2 random numbers, like `x = rand() << 15 | rand()`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: There are no alternatives, other than using something that is extremely slow because it's intended for cryptography, using third party libraries that cause "dependency hell", and writing your own implementation that's probably worse. A blanket statement like "never use `rand()`" is as silly as "never use C".

Comment: @Brendan I think you misunderstand. The recommendation against `rand()` is based on bad implementations in old libraries which may still be encountered.  Hence the genuine recommendation not to use this as in the reference above.  There are a) alternatives in the system libraries such as `random()` and also of course b) lighterweight and fast non-crypto generators such as eg [Ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).  So the general advice stands: [do not use rand()](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+not+use+rand()&oq=do+not+use+rand()). See that link for more.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: You should "never" use `random()` because it can't be used for repeatable results in multi-threaded programs, has the same `RAND_MAX` as `rand()`, and isn't supported by old libraries. You should also "never" use Ziggurat because it's overkill (too complicated) for things like card games designed for children.

Comment: @Brendan  [Ziggurat is a single header file](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat/blob/master/inst/include/Ziggurat.h) (and that is in C++ because I happen to like C++; there are C alternatives out there too). If that is too heavy for you ...  Lastly, "don't use `rand()`, use `random()`" is not something I made up.  It's in the Linux manual pages.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Third party libraries should "never" be used (too much hassle to maintain project dependencies). C++ should also "never" be used (things like templates have a huge effect on compile times). Are you starting to see my point about the idiocy of "blanket never" statements?

Comment: I presume you read zero of the discussions about poor `rand()` quality, and of course did not consult the reference in my first comment above. You are entangling me in a nonsense debate that has little to do with the OP's question.  I move on now as I have better things to do.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: The problem here is that you're making up potentially false assumptions (e.g. that perfect distribution matters for the OP) and then using those assumptions as the basis for "blanket never" statements without qualifiers (like "if you care about even distribution, then...") while ignoring the fact that (with a different set of potentially false assumptions) `rand()` may be the best possible choice (even if the quality is worse).

Comment: @Brendan: The only appearance of “never” in comments here is in your comments. You misconstrued, misrepresented, and misquoted what another person wrote and then attacked the false representation.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use [`rand()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html), because it is quite poor in many C standard library implementations. It will return a pseudorandom number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, inclusive, but `RAND_MAX` is often relatively small; for example, 32767.

Using the modulo operator to yield a range of integers is problematic if the range is a large fraction of the range of values the generator function can return, because the distribution is not exactly uniform.

For example, let's say `RAND_MAX` is 59999, and we used `rand() % 40000`. The probability of the result being between 0 and 19999 is 67%, but only 33% between 20000 and 39999. This is because that `rand()` produces a value in [0,19999] at 1/3 probability, [20000,39999] at 1/3 probability, and [40000..59999] at 1/3 probability; but that last third folds back so that it yields [0,19999] after the modulo operation!

For small ranges the bias is not so noticeable.

Personally, I like to generate enough random bits to cover the desired range, then use the exclusion method to pick the value.

If we need to use `rand()`, we can use the following helper function to generate a pseudorandom number whose range is at least `atleast` (but may be larger; i.e. it can return a larger value):

```
#include <inttypes.h>

static inline uint64_t  rand_atleast(uint64_t  atleast)
{
    uint64_t  result = 0;
    do {
        result = ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1) * result + (uint64_t)rand();
        atleast /= ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1);
    } while (atleast > 0);
    return result;
}
```

To use the exclusion method to create `int`s within a desired range, we can use a structure to contain the stuff we need, a helper function to initialize that range (to describe some specific range of ints), and another helper function to generate integers within that range:

```
struct range_spec {
    uint64_t  mask;
    uint64_t  limit;
    int       base;
};

static inline void set_range(struct range_spec *spec,
                             int minimum, int maximum)
{
    uint64_t  mask;
    int       base;

    if (minimum <= maximum) {
        base = minimum;
        mask = maximum - minimum;
    } else {
        base = maximum;
        mask = minimum - maximum;
    }

    spec->base  = base;
    spec->limit = mask;

    mask |= mask >> 1;
    mask |= mask >> 2;
    mask |= mask >> 4;
    mask |= mask >> 8;
    mask |= mask >> 16;
    mask |= mask >> 32;

    spec->mask = mask;
}

static inline int rand_range(const struct range_spec *spec)
{
    const uint64_t  mask = spec->mask;
    const uint64_t  limit = spec->limit;
    uint64_t        result;

    do {
        result = rand_atleast(mask) & mask;
    } while (result > limit);

    return spec->base + result;
}
```

However, this is a lot of work to get pretty poor pseudorandom numbers: not worth it in my opinion.

---

I usually use Xorshift64* instead.  It is fast, quite random (see [this extended comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53900430/1475978) of mine), and really easy to implement.

Essentially, you can use a small header file, say **rng64.h**:

```
#ifndef   RNG64_H
#define   RNG64_H
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    uint64_t  limit;
    int64_t   base;
    int       shift;
} rng64_intrange_spec;

static uint64_t  rng64_state = 1;

static inline uint64_t  rng64(void)
{
    uint64_t  x = rng64_state;
    x ^= x >> 12;
    x ^= x << 25;
    x ^= x >> 27;
    rng64_state = x;
    return x * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
}

static inline uint64_t  rng64_randomize(void)
{
    uint64_t  x;
    int       n = 1000;

    x = ((uint64_t)time(NULL) * UINT64_C(19076794157513))
      ^ ((uint64_t)clock() * UINT64_C(809712647));
    if (!x)
        x = 1;
    while (n-->0) {
        x ^= x >> 12;
        x ^= x << 25;
        x ^= x >> 27;
    }

    rng64_state = x;
    return x;
}

static inline double rng64_one(void)
{
    return (double)rng64() / 18446744073709551616.0;
}

static inline int64_t rng64_intrange(rng64_intrange_spec *spec)
{
    const uint64_t  limit = spec->limit;
    const int       shift = spec->shift;
    uint64_t        value;

    do {
        value = rng64() >> shift;
    } while (value > limit);

    return spec->base + value;
}

static inline void rng64_set_intrange(rng64_intrange_spec *spec,
                                  int64_t minimum,
                                  int64_t maximum)
{
    int64_t   base;
    uint64_t  limit;
    int       bits = 0;

    if (minimum <= maximum) {
        base  = minimum;
        limit = maximum - minimum;
    } else {
        base  = maximum;
        limit = minimum - maximum;
    }

    spec->base  = base;
    spec->limit = limit;

    while (limit >= 32768) {
        limit >>= 16;
        bits   += 16;
    }
    while (limit >= 8) {
        limit >>= 4;
        bits   += 4;
    }
    while (limit > 0) {
        limit >>= 1;
        bits   += 1;
    }

    spec->shift = 64 - bits;
}

#endif /* RNG64_H */
```

Somewhere near the beginning of your program, call `rng64_randomize()` to generate a state based on the current time (wall clock via `time()`, and CPU time used to execute the current process via `clock()`). The initial state is churned a bit, to ensure you don't get similar sequences when running the code in quick succession.  You can set the `rng64_state` to any value except zero, to generate a specific sequence. (Zero state will generate only zeroes.) I recommend using

```
printf("Using %" PRIu64 " as the Xorshift64* random number seed.\n", rng64_randomize());
```

which prints both the seed, and the pseudorandom number generator algorithm used, near the beginning of the program. That allows someone to reproduce the test (by setting `rng64_state` to that value instead of calling `rng64_randomize()`, or reimplement the test using their own equivalent code).  Reproducibility is good.

While `(uint64_t)time(NULL)` is not guaranteed to work by the C standard, it does work in all current widely-used C implementations I am aware of.

If you want to compare to a different pseudorandom number generator, just reimplement another using a similar header file, and include that instead. That way you don't need to change any code that uses the generator, only the generator code itself.

`rng_one()` returns uniform pseudorandom numbers between 0 and 1.0, inclusive. If you want the upper limit to be exclusive, use e.g.

```
static inline double rng64_one(void)
{
    double  r;
    do {
        r = (double)rng64() / 18446744073709551616.0;
    } while (r >= 1.0);
    return r;
}
```

and if both limits exclusive (so it never returns 0.0 or 1.0 exactly), `while (r <= 0.0 || r >= 1.0);` instead.

Here's an example of how to use the rng64.h above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rng64.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rng64_intrange_spec  r;
    int   minval, maxval, count, i;
    char  dummy;

    if (argc != 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s MIN MAX COUNT\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program outputs COUNT pseudorandom integers,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "between MIN and MAX, inclusive.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %d %c", &minval, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid minimum.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %d %c", &maxval, &dummy) != 1 || maxval < minval) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid maximum.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (sscanf(argv[3], " %d %c", &count, &dummy) != 1 || count < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid count.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Generating %d pseudorandom integers in [%d, %d],\n", count, minval, maxval);
    fprintf(stderr, "using Xorshift64* with seed %" PRIu64 ".\n", rng64_randomize());
    fflush(stderr);

    rng64_set_intrange(&r, minval, maxval);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%d\n", (int)rng64_intrange(&r));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Specify the minimum and maximum values (integers), and the number of integers to output, as command-line parameters.

Comment: It's a good answer, just like your other answer that you reference, but it does not really answer the question the OP asked which was (much) simpler ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Good point. How about this edited version?